# How do I unescape some backslashes but not all in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using tinyperl with the following script:

```
@lines=<STDIN>;
foreach (@lines) {
    s/\\(.)/($1 eq '"' or $1 eq '\\') ? $1 : '\\' . $1/eg;
    print;
}
```

I would like each backslash to be considered only with the following character, and remove the backslash only if the following character is a double quote or another backslash. (I know this purpose might be unsound to you, but never mind).

For example, I would like to translate `abc\ndef\\ghi\"\\\n` to `abc\ndef\ghi"\\n`. But this script seems to translate it to `abcndef\ghi"\n` instead.

Could you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
s/\\([\\"])/$1/g;
```

The `[]` gives a character class that matches either a backslash or a double quote so we are saying replace a backslash followed by either another backslash or double quote with whichever character in the character class matched.

Comment: won't this also remove my `backslash`or `"` along with the backslash? Also, will perl eat two characters each time he will encounter a backslash? (ps. markdown is sometimes a bit buggy)

Comment: @Benoit You may have seen the very first version of my answer which was posted briefly before I edited it so that the second matching character is not removed. Please try with the revised solution and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a look-ahead assertion ([see the section in perlre on Extended Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)).

```
s/\\(?=[\\"])//g;
```

Comment: I think this will replace \\\\\\a with \a only, because it does not eat up the second slash each time…